# The king had a place to move, how is this checkmate?

Tags: checkmate

The king had a place to move, how is this checkmate?

[image]

Comment: To which square do you think the king can move? The queen gives check and covers c2, the knee ght covers e1 and there are white pieces on all the other squares.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** This is checkmate because White cannot (1) move the King out of check, (2) block the check, or (3) capture the piece giving check.

**1. Move out of Check:**
The White King cannot move to the c1, d2, or e2-squares as those squares are occupied by White's own pieces (the dark-squared Bishop, the d-pawn, and the Queen, respectively).

This leaves the c2-square and e1-square as the only potential escapes. The White King cannot move to c2 because of Black's Queen on b3, and the Black Knight prevents escaping to e1.

**2. Block the Check:**
White has no piece that can legally move to c2 to block the check.

**3. Capture the Piece giving Check:**
White has no legal move to capture the Black Queen on b3.

```
[Title "Checkmate"]
[FEN "r1b1kb1r/ppp2ppp/5n2/3p4/4p3/PqPnP1PP/RP1PQPB1/1NBK2NR w - - 0 1"]
```